# Operate within a group by and populate additional columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframes as below:

```
+------+------+---+------+
|field1|field2|id |Amount|
+------+------+---+------+
|A     |B     |002|10.0  |
|A     |B     |003|12.0  |
|A     |B     |005|15.0  |
|C     |B     |002|20.0  |
|C     |B     |003|22.0  |
|C     |B     |005|25.0  |
+------+------+---+------+
```

I need to convert it to :

```
+------+------+---+-------+---+-------+---+-------+
|field1|field2|002|002_Amt|003|003_Amt|005|005_Amt|
+------+------+---+-------+---+-------+---+-------+
|A     |B     |002|10.0   |003|12.0   |005|15.0   |
|C     |B     |002|20.0   |003|22.0   |005|25.0   |
+------+------+---+-------+---+-------+---+-------+
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 1):

Your final `dataframe` column depends on `id` column so you need to store the *distinct id*s in a separate `array`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val distinctIds = df.select(collect_list("id")).rdd.first().get(0).asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[String]].distinct
```

Next step is to `filter` each of the `distinctIds` and `join` them

```
val first = distinctIds.head
var finalDF = df.filter($"id" === first).withColumnRenamed("id", first).withColumnRenamed("Amount", first+"_Amt")
for(str <- distinctIds.tail){
  var tempDF = df.filter($"id" === str).withColumnRenamed("id", str).withColumnRenamed("Amount", str+"_Amt")
  finalDF = finalDF.join(tempDF, Seq("field1", "field2"), "left")
}
finalDF.show(false)
```

You should have your desired output as

```
+------+------+---+-------+---+-------+---+-------+
|field1|field2|002|002_Amt|003|003_Amt|005|005_Amt|
+------+------+---+-------+---+-------+---+-------+
|A     |B     |002|10.0   |003|12.0   |005|15.0   |
|C     |B     |002|20.0   |003|22.0   |005|25.0   |
+------+------+---+-------+---+-------+---+-------+
```

`Var` is never recommended for *scala*. So you can create a *recursive function* to do the above logic as below

```
def getFinalDF(first: Boolean, array: List[String], df: DataFrame, tdf: DataFrame) : DataFrame = array match {
  case head :: tail => {
    if(first) {
      getFinalDF(false, tail, df, df.filter($"id" === head).withColumnRenamed("id", head).withColumnRenamed("Amount", head + "_Amt"))
    }
    else{
      val tempDF = df.filter($"id" === head).withColumnRenamed("id", head).withColumnRenamed("Amount", head+"_Amt")
      getFinalDF(false, tail, df, tdf.join(tempDF, Seq("field1", "field2"), "left"))
    }
  }
  case Nil => tdf
}
```

and call the *recursive function* as

```
getFinalDF(true, distinctIds.toList, df, df).show(false)
```

You should have the same output.